# Does order of javascript import matter?

Tags: javascript, .net, web

I have an aspx page and imports jQuery, jTemplate and Flexigrid

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/flexigrid.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-jtemplates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.json-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Does the order of import statements above matter?

Comment: Yes, scripts are loaded synchronously, in-order, so if script *B* has a dependency on script *A* then you should ensure that the `<script>` tag for *A* appears before that for *B*.

Comment: Fast-forwarding to year 2020, I can't believe this was a thing. Now with `import` or `require`, the order wouldn't matter but the order on HTML still matters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, **if** a script uses anything defined by another script during its initial load. Each script is loaded and evaluated in order, synchronously. (The downloads may be in parallel if the browser wants, but they'll be *evaluated* in order unless the [`defer` or `async` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) were specified and are supported by the browser.)

So for instance, at a guess I'd say at least the last two scripts use the `jQuery` symbol defined by the first script, and so they must appear after it, or you'll see errors like `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`.

The order of *unrelated* scripts doesn't matter, but where they build on each other (as in this case), it does.