# Bxslider Images not loading until I refresh the Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-tabs, bxslider

So I have this page where I have a bxslider with images inside some tabs, I have the bxslider function set to load before the tabs but when I go to the tab where the bxslider is the images haven't loaded. When I refresh the page they will be there. How do I get them to load so that when a person goes to that tab they are already there and not a blank section? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/r1ma11tj/

There are a lot of missing images, sorry I'm not sure how to add images to jsfiddles. Here's a live link to look at...

http://morecleanenergy.com/graphics/testing/mass/Mass.html

This is my call function right before the body tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
     $('#tab-container').easytabs();
 });
  </script>
```

The bxslider is on the Why CEC page, it has a light blue background and it's the second item from the top.

Comment: Are you adding your function on the CEC page?

Comment: Well everything is on one page, so there are no external pages being loaded for the tabs, each page is in a div tag one on top of the other.

Comment: An you've got `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>` before your function?

Comment: Yup, those are at the very top of the page. :-/

Comment: Does it matter what order the scripts at the top of the page are in? Like should the bxslider.js file script be above the easytabs.js?

Comment: You can refer to [Does order of javascript import matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827652/does-order-of-javascript-import-matter) for the order of scripts

Comment: Well I put them in order and it still isn't loading until I refresh the page... -_-;;

Comment: I don't see any Why CEC page, and the fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: I ended up changing the way I pull my pages into the tabs, instead opting for an ajax call that pulls them in and loads them all initially.

Answer (score 1):

/**
 * BxSlider v4.1.2 - Fully loaded, responsive content slider
 * http://bxslider.com
 *
 * Copyright 2014, Steven Wanderski - http://stevenwanderski.com - http://bxcreative.com
 * Written while drinking Belgian ales and listening to jazz
 *
 * Released under the MIT license - http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

/*! jQuery v3.0.0-alpha1 | (c) jQuery Foundation | jquery.org/license */

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined**

use jQuery v1.9, solved.

/*! jQuery v1.9.1 | (c) 2005, 2012 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license